# Rectangle Leaves it mark behind while MouseMove

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to create a rectangle and colour the inverse (area outside that rectangle) area.

```
Gdiplus::Region *cropRegion = new Gdiplus::Region(cropRectF);
Gdiplus::Rect gdiCropRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f, 1000.0f);

Gdiplus::Rect imageContainer(0.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f, 1000.0f);
Gdiplus::Region *completeRegion = new Gdiplus::Region(imageContainer);
completeRegion->Intersect(cropRegion);

gdiGraphics.SetClip(completeRegion, Gdiplus::CombineModeXor);

Gdiplus::GraphicsPath *cropRectPath = new Gdiplus::GraphicsPath();
cropRectPath->AddRectangle(cropRectF);

Gdiplus::Pen* myPen = new Gdiplus::Pen(Gdiplus::Color::White);
myPen->SetWidth(1);
gdiGraphics.DrawPath(myPen, cropRectPath);

Gdiplus::SolidBrush dimmingBrush(Gdiplus::Color::MakeARGB(50, 0, 0, 0));
gdiGraphics.FillRegion(&dimmingBrush, completeRegion);
```

The code till here works perfectly fine,

However when I try to move this rectangle using mouse movements in MouseMove CallBack, it moves but it leaves white traces behind.

I tried to call InvalidateRect in the end but then my rectangle doesn't moves at all.
Any Idea how can old rectangle can be cleared.
I am using GDI+ and C++.
Thanks

Comment: You are not erasing the background.  Only draw in the WM_PAINT message handler.  Call InvalidateRect() to trigger it.

Comment: call InvalidateRect() in your MouseMove callback function.

Comment: Well, @HansPassant, I am drawing it in MouseMove CAllBack, as I have mentioned in my original Question, I tried calling InvalidateRect in the end but then my rectangle doesn't moves at all.

[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It says that you can draw without WM_PAINT event as well using GetDC.
My Graphics is created with HDC only

Gdiplus::Graphics gdiGraphics(hDC);